# Making AngularJS + JQuery Isotope + Dynamic content play well together

Tags: jquery, websocket, angularjs, dynamic-data, jquery-isotope

In my page AngularJS' html templates are bound to the controller's variables as usual.
I'm using WebSockets & when I receive a new item I update the scope's values and call angular's $apply. This works fine, AngularJS correctly updates the view rendering any new items added/removed...

The tricky part is bringing the [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) plugin into the mix.
Since the content is dynamic adding items to Isotope ( http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/adding-items.html ) isn't straightforward for a few reasons:

- On updating the controller's data and calling apply angular creates the additional elements required.
- Isotope requires you to know each item you want to add.
- I don't think there is a way for AngularJS to tell the controller what html item was created.

Has anyone gotten these 3 pieces of to work together?
Is there a way of getting the HTML created so it can be passed to Isotope?

Comment: Having jQuery isotope and AngularJS play nice together is not always straightforward, I implemented a native AngularJS alternative to isotope (work in progress):
 
http://tristanguigue.github.io/angular-dynamic-layout/ 

In that case you wouldn't have to worry about having to watch your items to know if any have been inserted since the directive triggers a layout for any changes in the items provided from the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume you are using ng-repeat to generate the view/HTML.

Here's something you can try: create a directive and attach it to the same element where the ng-repeat(s) is/are.  Set the directive's `priority` such that it runs last (or after other directives).  Have the directive's link function watch the same $scope properties that you updated as a result of the web sockets information (or I suppose you could just create some kind of counter on the scope that you increment each time something changes -- watch that counter in the directive).  When the directive/watch detects a change, extract the new HTML (via the link function's `element` attribute) and send it to isotope.

You'll probably need to set some scope properties in the controller that the watch callback can access to determine which items were added/removed.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, someController) {
    scope.$watch(..., function(newValue) {
       // extract HTML with Angular or jQuery
       var children = element.children();
       for(i=scope.first_new_item; i<= scope.last_new_item; i++) {
           $('#isotope_container').isotope('insert'), children[i]);
       }
       // handle removed items similarly ??
    }
```

contents() might work better than children(), or use jQuery selectors.

Comment: That's a good idea. Thanks. Hadn't used the link phase in Angular yet so good time to try. I ended up using jQuery selectors and other than a few variations to fit my use case your idea worked alright! :D

Answer (score 0):

Had some trouble down this route and happy to find this, Mark's solution is right on.

the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) library is helpful if the height of your isotope elements is dynamic and depends on images.